# Which connection string is deprecated?

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I'm checking out a customer's files and not being a godlikely savvy on SQL, I'm not sure which of the following syntaxes is to be preferred or more modern. Both seem to do the same thing so I may as well leave them be but I like to work in a consequent manner.

```
String 
  con1 = "Server=ServerName;Database=DbName;Trusted_Connection=Yes;",
  con2 = "Data Source=Servername;Initial Catalog=DbName;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
```

?!

Comment: [Neither is deprecated, and different providers can have different syntax](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012).

Comment: If this is from .NET code you could use the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class (I think that's its name...)